# How to submit form using Bootstrap Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I am using [Bootstrapvalidation](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator) to check my input fields. On top of that, I have additional check that is done on submit. It's either submitted without showing errors or, when I use this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
});

$("#submit-form").on("click", function(){
    var valid=some code for additional check;
    if (valid) {
        $("#form").submit();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
```

But then it's just all recursive and the form doesn't get submitted. How to I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Harshil's answer covers the [bootstrapValidation](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) plugin which is totally a different plugin then [1000hz BootstrapValidator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator) plugin

In your approach, you have `ev.preventDefault();` in first script which is separate script and preventing the form to submit doesn't matter the input fields / additional check are valid or invalid and the input states / additional check valid or invalid not defined in first script at all.

what you need is [Conditionally handling the submit event](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events) to check and handle the `additional custom check` along with other form input fields to validate and if all good, submit the form,

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
  }
})
```

Comment: This is what I need. It's just that I didn't have class "form-group" before my submit button, so the whole thing didn't work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Refer following example

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taskForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                task: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The task is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                description: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The description is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            if (data.fv.getInvalidFields().length > 0) {    // There is invalid field
                data.fv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="taskForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Task</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <!-- Initially, the submit button is disabled -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure I can get this Submit button to ever be enabled.
I am using this http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator and I have:
<form id="form" data-toggle="validator" action="test.php">. My validation is inline.